# Angular 11 - '“/node_modules/firebase/index”' has no exported member 'User'

Tags: angular

Namespace

```
c:/Users/surendra/Documents/AngularProject/EcommerceApp/node_modules/firebase/index
```

has no exported member `User`.

**Angular and Fire Versions**

[image: Angular and Fire Versions]

Any help Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out any of the following commands:

```
npm uninstall angularfire2
npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.9
```

OR

```
npm install --save firebase@latest
```

**EDIT**

```
npm uninstall @angular/fire
npm install @angular/fire
ng add @angular/fire
```

Hope that it would work!

Comment: The two methods didnt work for me ... still showing the same error.

Comment: Ok, then you could try the other command set; edited the answer :)

Comment: Could you try declaring `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'; ` accordingly, if not declared already ?